# Customer cancelled order and didn't paid for it? Can i take him to court

Tags: freelance-websites

If a customer get the work from seller and in the end he cancelled what should seller do?what should be his action? Can he take him to court?

Comment: is there a valid contract between the customer and the seller?

Comment: Yes it was but he reviewed order then cancelled

Comment: If he "got the work" then he didn't "cancel" anything. Sue.

Comment: I don't recommend this. You can't take him to court unless you've mentioned about charges for the same before ordering.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of all this ?

Answer (score 0):

Too many unknowns to definitively answer the title.

However, with regard to:

> what should seller do?what should be his action?

You can partially protect yourself from these situations **by taking part-payment up front**. e.g., you might request:

- 30% to begin
- 30% at an agreed mid-point
- 40% when the project is completed/launched

That way, if things turn bad, you ideally have at least something to show for it. So, the seller's future action should be to **adjust payment terms before commencing the next project** with any client.